# Your build is currently configured to use Java 21 and Gradle 8.3

Tags: java, gradle

I am using a Spring Boot Application with Java 21 and Gradle I also tried the nightly gradle build 8.4 and 8.5 but still I got this error.

> Your build is currently configured to use Java 21 and Gradle 8.3.

Comment: How do you know it's an error and not an ominous info text?

Comment: What command did you use? What was in the output around that line you highlighted? Where do you see that message? Is the text of the line you shared complete?

Comment: I used gradle build and this was a error message because it hasn't start building.

Comment: What is the full output from Gradle?

Comment: I'm on a mac, i had the same issue. I solved it by accepting the new xcode license, running: sudo xcodebuild -license